# Generating a html <li> tag using php dynamically

Tags: php, html

I am pulling out a date value in the format 2012-12-28 from a database and now I need to create a html li element using the date value.

The li elements are in the following form which have an id and calls two javascript functions.

```
<li id="date2012-12-28" onClick="showUser('2012-12-28'); getID(this.id);">2012-12-28</li>
```

In this example the date "2012-12-28" is a variable value from the database.

How can I construct a php query to generate these links dynamically?

For example

```
echo '<li id="' . $value . + "onClick="showUser('" . $value . "');" ....
```

Thanks

Comment: what is the type of result? you can use `foreach` or `for` or `while`

Comment: I am using a while loop at the moment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the result set you would iterate over it with a foreach, so something like:

```
<?php foreach($result as $row){?>
<li id="date<?=$row['date'];?>" onClick="showUser('<?=$row['date'];?>'); getID(this.id);"><?=$row['date'];?></li>
<?php } ?>
```

or

```
<?php 
foreach($result as $row){
    echo '<li id="date'.$row['date'].'" onClick="showUser(\''.$row['date'].'\'); getID(this.id);">'.$row['date'].'</li>';
}
?>
```